# Case Select syntax is creating a Loop I do not want

Tags: excel, vba, select, case, goto

I have written a syntax which includes case select and a msgbox. I want the syntax to find the first active cell in the spreadsheet and move it to A1 or A2 based on some predetermined questions and answers, but the commands are not working optimally. can somene help me out?

I want the messagebox to pop up intuitively based on the answers provided to previous questions, but there seems to be a mishap in terms of the message box ending up in a loop.

I have attached the code underneath.

```
Public Sub SurvAnalysis()

    Dim InpSh As Worksheet
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim msg1 As String, msg2 As String
    Dim Ans1 As Variant, Ans2 As Variant

    Set InpSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

    msg1 = "Are these headers included in the Data, and is the data in the correct format? { Dob ∏ StartDate ∏ End Date }"
    Ans1 = MsgBox(msg1, vbYesNoCancel, " Data type")

    Select Case Ans1
        Case vbYes
            On Error Resume Next
            Set fCell = InpSh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                        After:=InpSh.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), _
                                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If fCell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "All cells are blank."
            Else
                fCell.CurrentRegion.Cut Destination:=InpSh.Range("A1")
            End If
            GoTo Quit:

        Case vbCancel
            MsgBox ("Get your data sorted out")
            GoTo Quit:

        Case vbNo
            GoTo Option2:
    End Select

Quit:
Option2:

    msg2 = "Are the data in the correct manner and do you wish for us to include the headers on your behalf?"
    Ans = MsgBox(msg2, vbYesNo, "Sort Data")

    Select Case Ans
        Case vbYes
            Set fCell = InpSh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                        After:=InpSh.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), _
                                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False)
            If fCell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "All cells are blank."
            Else
                fCell.CurrentRegion.Cut Destination:=InpSh.Range("A2")
                InpSh.Range("A1").Value = " Dob"
                InpSh.Range("B1").Value = " StartDate"
                InpSh.Range("C1").Value = " End Date"
            End If
        Case vbNo
            MsgBox ("Get your data sorted out")
            GoTo Quit:
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-

question)

Comment: I think the question is reasonable.  the OP clearly stated the issue they were having, and can't figure out why.

Comment: Thank you R.Roe. I am asking a question because I do not know how to figure out what I am trying to achieve and being all philosophical on a programming page is rather petty david.G

Answer (score 3):

Your goto ending statement `Quit:` should be at the very end. In your code when it goes to `Quit:` it will continue on and process all the code lines below it.  Also just as a general rule of thumb and this may be opinion but usually you can always right code without having to use any `goto` statement.  They cause more issues than what it's worth.  See if you can write your logic without any `goto` statements and you'll be set for life.

Comment: Make sure you mark as answer if you think it answered your question.

Comment: Hi R.Roe, even after I excluded the goto statement the "conditional" msgbox still pops up even when those conditions are not met.

Comment: did you move all the code for `option2` where you call your `option2 goto` statement in side your case statement?  Otherwise it will always execute the code for `option2`

Comment: I fixed it using an if statement instead. it actually worked out, but thanks again

Comment: @KokoEtokebe "it actually worked out," <-- mind to share your solution to this post? This will help to remove this question from SO 'unanswered' list.